# Why are my custom modules not displaying in a Blog Post in Orchard Core CMS?

Tags: orchardcms, orchard-modules, orchardcore

I created a custom module for Orchard Core CMS and while I can get it to edit and display in a custom content type and edit in the Blog Post content type is does not display in the Blog Post content type. How do I get the content of the custom module to display in a Blog Post content type?

I followed the tutorial here: https://www.dotnetthailand.com/web-frameworks/orchard-core-cms/create-a-custom-orchard-core-cms-module.

I implemented the custom module to be able to edit and display information in a content part by creating a display driver and views without a controller (there was a dummy Home controller that never rendered output).

I created a custom content type and added my custom part to that content type. I can edit and display the content part as expected.

When I added the custom part to a predefined blog post content type I could edit the content part as expected but it does not display in the blog post. I was expecting it would work the same for a blog post as for custom content.